# System sounds in Android

Tags: android, audio

So I need to play jangle (error sound?) when user crosses the border of my custom View, I can't use notifications sounds. So how I can find this sound?

Comment: You need a **rooted** device, in order to access the `/system/media/audio/` folder.

Comment: @DerGolem hmm, I don't think about it, thank you.

Comment: OR... simply download a **custom rom** (or better, the `original rom`). Open the zip with a compression program and extract the audio file. But maybe that file is not there. You have to dowload the original rom for your device.